# Converting MIDI events to pygame events

Tags: python, pygame, midi

I'm trying to get input from my MIDI device (keyboard) to be used in pygame code. It looks like `pygame.midi.midis2events()` would be perfect but they don't tell you what they mean by `midis` which is a necessary argument for the function.

> `pygame.midi.midis2events()` converts midi events to pygame events
>
> ```
> midis2events(midis, device_id) -> [Event, ...]
> ```

My question is just what do they mean by `midis`? I can't find anywhere online where this is specified.

Comment: `midis` must be midi events that you get when reading from the input buffer (by using [`read()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Input.read) method on a [`pygame.midi.Input`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Input) object)

Comment: Ok. I also couldn't figure out how to use read() because they don't specifiy what num_events means. Is there somewhere where they do specify all of this stuff because the information on this webpage seems to be incomplete. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.get_count   I don't know what I'm doing though so maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

`midis` is the list of MIDI events returned by `read()`.

One [example](https://github.com/bgr/midistuff/blob/master/piano.py) uses it as follows:

```
while not quit:

    # Blit the picture ...
    ...

    # Check for keypresses

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ...

    for event in midis2events.midis2events(midi_in.read(40), midi_in_id):
        if event.command == midis2events.NOTE_ON:
            play_note(Note().from_int(event.data1))
        ...

    # Update the screen

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What is 'midi_in' for the '.read()' function? The device ID doesn't work. I also get this error for the 'read()' function. TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num_events'

Comment: I linked to the example program.

Comment: Oh! Thanks I totally missed that.